# On preserving dried ginger

Tags: food-preservation, ginger, drying

Based on my reading, preserving dried ginger is the same as preserving fresh ginger I.e airtight and in the fridge.

Is there anything more that can be done to preserve the dried version.  After dehydrating it, will not grounding it immediately and instead grounding it at the point of use make a significant difference?

Comment: you could probably vacuum it for longer preservation.

Answer (score 3):

Dried ginger [can be kept at room temperature](https://www.eatbydate.com/other/spice-menu/how-long-does-ginger-last-shelf-life/), in any cool dark place (like your pantry), for months to years:

> Dried, ground, or crystallized ginger should be stored in a cool dark pantry in a sealed container. Spices with the moisture removed do not really go bad (unless they get wet), but they lose their potency over time and will no longer add flavor to food. If the aroma is gone, the flavor is most likely also gone from the dried ginger.

That's the whole point of drying it; so that it lasts longer without refrigeration.

Comment: Is it better to grind the dried version at point of use or will it be loosing its aroma as you say when dried regardless of whether you ground it therefore ground dried ginger is the same as just dried ginger if they are the same age?  Thanks

Comment: For *any* dried spice, it keeps longer the bigger the pieces are.  So you'd want to wait to grind it if you can.